# How to query table meta data in Cloudera impala

Tags: impala

Is it possible to query table meta data in Cloudera Impala?

for example, I want to get list of tables which are created after a specific date?

OR I want to know list of tables which are created with parquet storage format.

OR I want to know list of tables with a specific column name.

Are there any meta data tables that I can query for this?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible today. You can track this feature via [IMPALA-1761](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-1761), though it is not currently committed to one of the upcoming releases.